# Can't Unity draw fine and smooth line?

Tags: unity, opengl, shaders, graphics, ios

I'm working on drawing lines in `Unity`, but find there is no way to draw clear, fine and smooth line in `Unity`, neither `LineRenderer` nor `GL.LINES`, both of them got jaggy, pixelated and coarse lines, even set `Anti-Aliasing` to `8x`, just a tiny improvement. But when I turn to see `iOS`, I find it's easy to draw perfect and smooth line with the original `iOS Graphic API`, just as the screenshot of `Paper` app in `iOS` below, while we can see the screenshot of Unity drawing with `LineRenderer`, it's really ugly, even use `Bezier`, still jaggy.

Isn't there any way to draw smooth line in `Unity`? Will `Shader` do some great help? Does anyone have a good idea? Very appreciate it.

**Paper on iOS**

[image: Paper app in iOS]

**Unity with `LineRenderer`**

[image: Unity Drawing with <code>LineRenderer</code>]

Comment: What resolution are you rendering your game in?

Comment: @ZEKE, it looks like you've already figured out my problem. Before that I used the `Default Is Native Resolution` and kept the `Low Resolution Aspect Ratios` at top of `Game` view turned on, now I get clear lines. Thank you so much!

Comment: good to hear! Still, I think you should add your fix as an answer, that way others with the same problem can find it more easily.

Comment: @ZEKE, yes, I will do that :)

Answer (score 2):

@ZEKE briefly figured out the problem might be wrong settings of game rendering resolution. When I looked into it I found there had been a `Low Resolution Aspect Ratios` option checked on at top of `Unity Game view > Free Aspect`, I tried turning off it, then got clear lines.

(Meanwhile, I've also tried changing the `Default Is Native Resolution` in `Player Settings` to something like `3000x2000`, but it looked none affection to this issue)

Thanks to @ZEKE!